# Prevent routerlink being triggered from specific child elements

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routerlink

I have something like:

```
<ion-item
        *ngFor="let recipe of recipes"
        [routerLink]="['./',recipe.id]"
      >
        <ion-avatar><ion-img [src]="recipe.imageURL"></ion-img></ion-avatar>
        <ion-label>{{ recipe.name }}</ion-label>
        <ion-button
          (click)="deleteRecipe(recipe.id)"
          color="danger"
          ><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon
        ></ion-button>
      </ion-item>
```

Which work as whenever I click on the item consistenting of an image, text and a delete button (and all the whitespace from the ion-item) we get redirected to the details page.
I am wondering if it is possible to override this navigation where we stay on the same page when clicking the delete button?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to return false on the method you are calling. This will prevent the routerlink from getting fired.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I had to call both stopPropagation and preventDefault.

Example using @ionic/react v7.0.0:

```
    <IonItem routerLink="/some/path">
      <IonLabel>
        <h2>Item Title</h2>
        <p>Item Description</p>
      </IonLabel>
      <IonButton
        onClick={(e) => {
          // needs both to prevent item from navigating
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        <IonIcon icon={ellipsisHorizontal} />
      </IonButton>
    </IonItem>
```

I thought I only needed stopPropagation to prevent the event from bubbling up, then found this in the Ionic forums:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/clickable-ion-item-with-clickable-ion-icon-inside/183627

I didn't have access to stopPropagationImmediately and found that neither of the methods worked alone. Only the two as mentioned above.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the stopPropagation() event method on your button.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation